# malloc implementation from fixed size buffer

Tags: c, malloc

I need a generic malloc implementation that uses one big fixed-size buffer. Something similar to the "[Zero-malloc memory allocator](http://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html)" SQLite has. Do you know of any such implementations? It should be light-weight and portable that can be used for embedded applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your malloc?

Comment: @Mathk: Memory fragmentation (or not). Want to know before hand how much memory kernel will allocate to the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. **IF** you need something production quality and well tested, just borrow SQLite's allocator. SQLite's source code is very well-written, documented, extremely well-tested and has a very permissive open-source license.
2. **IF** you need something small and simple, either to learn or to use in an embedded environment, consider [this implementation](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/10/17/memmgr-a-fixed-pool-memory-allocator/) [shameless plug!] - just 350 LOC of commented C code.

Comment: I agree with some of the commenters on the post you linked to - this kind of allocator does nothing to solve the robustness problem for embedded systems (catastrophic fragmentation). OP should state the requirements better and consider whether what he asked for can really solve the problem.

Comment: @R: lack of fragmentation wasn't the aim of that allocator, but rather computing in a reliable way the total amount of heap memory required by embedded applications.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a simple implementation for testing purpose. I see that realloc is not implemented. I was planning to use it large code base which has reallocs also in use. I guess its best to port SQLite implementation as suggested you and others. I didn't do that as I expected someone else might have done it AND also because I am lazy :)

Comment: @Manish: realloc is simple to implement in terms of malloc and free

Answer (score 4):

The SQLite source code is freely available.  If you like that a particular implementation, why not use it?

Answer (score 1):

Most current `malloc` implementations work by carving up a large chunk of memory they obtained from the OS. If that block runs out, `malloc` asks the OS for a new large block.

You could base your own implementation on an existing `malloc` implementation (for example the [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) one), and instead of obtaining a block from the OS, you use a single static buffer. When that runs out, `malloc` will start failing, just as it does when the OS can't provide any new blocks.