# memory heap allocator library that keeps separate structures?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, boost

Here's my problem: I need to manage memory in a remote contiguous buffer that my program can't read or write to. It needs to have malloc()/free() semantics, and support setting minimum alignment, and fragmentation avoidance (whenever possible). Since I can't read or write to this buffer directly, I need to use local structures to manage all the allocations.

I am already using boost, so if something inside boost can be massaged to do this, that would be great. However, I'm not averse to using a C library or anything like that.

As an example, I need a non-IPC version  of:

```
boost::interprocess::basic_managed_external_buffer<
                     char,
                     boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<
                                          boost::interprocess::mutex_family,
                                          boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>,
                                          SOME_ALIGNMENT>,
                     boost::interprocess::iset_index>
```

preferably with malloc/free semantics instead of new/delete
but without it ever actually reading or writing to the underlying buffer (and keeping all the allocation information/data structures in a separate buffer)

Any ideas?

P.S. I don't want the boost::interprocess example to be misleading, I am just familiar with the interface so using it as an example. The application is not really interprocess, and the allocator would only be used from my application.

Specifically I would like to be able to manage a 16GB external buffer with allocation sizes from 128 bytes all the way to 512MB. This is strictly 64-bit code, but even then I would prefer the pointer type to be a template parameter so I can use uint64_t explicitly.

Comment: How large (or small) is that buffer? Can it be *very* large?

Comment: Specifically I would like to be able to manage a 16GB external buffer with allocation sizes from 128 bytes all the way to 512MB. Is that *very* large?

Comment: On what computer? On a supercomputer with a terabyte of RAM it would not be that big! And you should edit your question, not add information in comments.

Comment: Why does the type of computer matter?

Comment: If you have 1Tbyte of RAM, 16Gbyte is small. On my desktop, it is all the RAM!

Comment: But the 16GB buffer is remote -- as in for the purpose of this question it's not part of the computer running it, might not be RAM altogether, etc. It shouldn't really matter if I'm running this on a machine with 256MB or with 8GB of RAM, as long as I have enough space to store all the meta information (like the rb_tree of free chunk sizes and addresses for example) about the allocations, I will be fine

Comment: Sounds like a game VRAM manager.  A google of this might get you a hit or two.

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657516/malloc-implementation-from-fixed-size-buffer

Comment: I found this http://jinie.github.io/memmgr/ (with code at https://github.com/jinie/memmgr ) and http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/10/17/memmgr-a-fixed-pool-memory-allocator/ (with code at https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/tree/master/2008/memmgr ) - they might help.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah unfortunately both of those store the chunk headers in the same memory space, so wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah unfortunately, no, that one also writes headers before each chunk

Comment: I think it's going to be quite tricky to get a remote mechanism provide generalized allocator semantics. The difficult part is that, unlike shared memory, this doesn't translate to machine-level loads and stores (moves). Lacking that, to get those kinds of allocator semantics where we're just handed memory to do with as we please, we have to be able to detect when the memory is being modified by the client. Without a special interface for this, we might have to repeatedly scan the memory for changes in a separate thread, and sync the data constantly whenever it is modified with the server.

Comment: I also don't quite understand why writing things like chunk headers in the same memory space is a problem. Is the representation of this client-side memory space important for some reason, like serialization? Also I'm a bit confused by your description of "non-IPC", as technically any kind of remote connection is still IPC, even across different hardware and utilizing things like sockets. It's not just about shared memory on the same machine.

Comment: @Ike it can't touch the memory, it literally cannot read or write it. I don't know why this is confusing to people. I should have just phrased it as allocating yards of highway or something. It's not IPC because there is only one device that can read or write to this memory (a separate piece of hardware) so it's not "inter" anything, and the piece of hardware does not have a CPU, hence the need to have an allocator on a separate PC.

Comment: @YuriyRomanenko I'm very confused about this part. If you are looking for `malloc`-type semantics for memory you can't read or write, what's the point? Is it just to make the remote server/device allocate more memory? In that case, why not just call a function that doesn't return anything like `make_server_device_allocate_memory_that_i_wont_use` that sends a socket message, e.g.? Normally a memory allocator gives you back a memory address to bytes you allocated that you can read/write. That's true even for, say, GPU memory, but it has to map to/from your client (CPU) memory space.

Comment: @YuriyRomanenko So perhaps it might be less confusing if you just took `allocator` out of the equation, since here it sounds like we just need to send a command of some sort over to this device to tell it to increase the amount of memory it has allocated without even getting a pointer back to the newly-allocated block. An allocator is going to be all about giving you back a pointer to read/write the allocated memory, and here it doesn't sound like we actually need that.

Comment: @YuriyRomanenko Or I think I understand now (correct me if wrong). You have this remote device providing like a big old block of opaque memory you can't directly read of write, so you have to send device-specific commands over to it to tell it what to do with its own memory. You're interested in allocators since you want the PC-side to keep track of what blocks are used vs. what are freed (and ready to be overwritten) as well as do alignment. Chunk headers are a no-no since you want to store that info on the PC side and not have to send more commands over to the device to create the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an update on what we actually wound up doing. I wound up implementing my own remote memory allocator (source below). It's spiritually similar to the [answer Sam suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31341162/1864889) but uses boost intrusive RB trees to avoid some of the log(N) lookups when freeing, joining etc. It's thread-safe and supports various remote pointer/offset types as template parameters. It's probably not ideal in a lot of ways, but it worked well enough for what we needed it to do. If you find bugs, let me know.

```
/*
 * Thread-safe remote memory allocator
 *
 * Author: Yuriy Romanenko
 * Copyright (c) 2015 Lytro, Inc.
 *
 */

#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/intrusive/rbtree.hpp>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

template<typename remote_ptr_t = void*,
         typename remote_size_t = size_t,
         typename remote_uintptr_t = uintptr_t>
class RemoteAllocator
{
    /* Internal structure used for keeping track of a contiguous block of
     * remote memory. It can be on one or two of the following RB trees:
     *    Free Chunks (sorted by size)
     *    All Chunks (sorted by remote pointer)
     */
    struct Chunk
    {
        bi::set_member_hook<> mRbFreeChunksHook;
        bi::set_member_hook<> mRbAllChunksHook;

        remote_uintptr_t mOffset;
        remote_size_t mSize;
        bool mFree;

        Chunk(remote_uintptr_t off, remote_size_t sz, bool fr)
                : mOffset(off), mSize(sz), mFree(fr)
        {

        }

        bool contains(remote_uintptr_t off)
        {
            return (off >= mOffset) && (off < mOffset + mSize);
        }
    private:
        Chunk(const Chunk&);
        Chunk& operator=(const Chunk&);
    };

    struct ChunkCompareSize : public std::binary_function <Chunk,Chunk,bool>
    {
        bool operator() (const Chunk& x, const Chunk& y) const
        {
            return x.mSize < y.mSize;
        }
    };
    struct ChunkCompareOffset : public std::binary_function <Chunk,Chunk,bool>
    {
        bool operator() (const Chunk& x, const Chunk& y) const
        {
            return x.mOffset < y.mOffset;
        }
    };

    typedef bi::rbtree<Chunk,
                       bi::member_hook<Chunk,
                                       bi::set_member_hook<>,
                                       &Chunk::mRbFreeChunksHook>,
                       bi::compare< ChunkCompareSize > > FreeChunkTree;

    typedef bi::rbtree<Chunk,
                       bi::member_hook<Chunk,
                                       bi::set_member_hook<>,
                                       &Chunk::mRbAllChunksHook>,
                       bi::compare< ChunkCompareOffset > > AllChunkTree;

    // Thread safety lock
    std::mutex mLock;
    // Size of the entire pool
    remote_size_t mSize;
    // Start address of the pool
    remote_ptr_t mStartAddr;

    // Tree of free chunks
    FreeChunkTree mFreeChunks;
    // Tree of all chunks
    AllChunkTree mAllChunks;

    // This removes the chunk from both trees
    Chunk *unlinkChunk(Chunk *c)
    {
        mAllChunks.erase(mAllChunks.iterator_to(*c));
        if(c->mFree)
        {
            mFreeChunks.erase(mFreeChunks.iterator_to(*c));
        }
        return c;
    }

    // This reinserts the chunk into one or two trees, depending on mFree
    Chunk *relinkChunk(Chunk *c)
    {
        mAllChunks.insert_equal(*c);
        if(c->mFree)
        {
            mFreeChunks.insert_equal(*c);
        }
        return c;
    }

    /* This assumes c is 'free' and walks the mAllChunks tree to the left
     * joining any contiguous free chunks into this one
     */
    bool growFreeLeft(Chunk *c)
    {
        auto it = mAllChunks.iterator_to(*c);
        if(it != mAllChunks.begin())
        {
            it--;
            if(it->mFree)
            {
                Chunk *left = unlinkChunk(&(*it));
                unlinkChunk(c);
                c->mOffset = left->mOffset;
                c->mSize = left->mSize + c->mSize;
                delete left;
                relinkChunk(c);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    /* This assumes c is 'free' and walks the mAllChunks tree to the right
     * joining any contiguous free chunks into this one
     */
    bool growFreeRight(Chunk *c)
    {
        auto it = mAllChunks.iterator_to(*c);
        it++;
        if(it != mAllChunks.end())
        {
            if(it->mFree)
            {
                Chunk *right = unlinkChunk(&(*it));
                unlinkChunk(c);
                c->mSize = right->mSize + c->mSize;
                delete right;
                relinkChunk(c);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public:
    RemoteAllocator(remote_size_t size, remote_ptr_t startAddr) :
        mSize(size), mStartAddr(startAddr)
    {
        /* Initially we create one free chunk the size of the entire managed
         * memory pool, and add it to both trees
         */
        Chunk *all = new Chunk(reinterpret_cast<remote_uintptr_t>(mStartAddr),
                               mSize,
                               true);
        mAllChunks.insert_equal(*all);
        mFreeChunks.insert_equal(*all);
    }

    ~RemoteAllocator()
    {
        auto it = mAllChunks.begin();

        while(it != mAllChunks.end())
        {
            Chunk *pt = unlinkChunk(&(*it++));
            delete pt;
        }
    }

    remote_ptr_t malloc(remote_size_t bytes)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        auto fit = mFreeChunks.lower_bound(
                    Chunk(reinterpret_cast<remote_uintptr_t>(mStartAddr),
                          bytes,
                          true));

        /* Out of memory */
        if(fit == mFreeChunks.end())
            return remote_ptr_t{0};

        Chunk *ret = &(*fit);
        /* We need to split the chunk because it's not the exact size */
        /* Let's remove the node */
        mFreeChunks.erase(fit);

        if(ret->mSize != bytes)
        {
            Chunk *right, *left = ret;

            /* The following logic decides which way the heap grows
             * based on allocation size. I am not 100% sure this actually
             * helps with fragmentation with such a big threshold (50%)
             *
             * Check if we will occupy more than half of the chunk,
             * in that case, use the left side. */
            if(bytes > ret->mSize / 2)
            {
                right = new Chunk(left->mOffset + bytes,
                                  left->mSize - bytes,
                                  true);
                relinkChunk(right);

                left->mSize = bytes;
                left->mFree = false;

                ret = left;
            }
            /* We'll be using less than half, let's use the right side. */
            else
            {
                right = new Chunk(left->mOffset + left->mSize - bytes,
                                  bytes,
                                  false);

                relinkChunk(right);

                left->mSize = left->mSize - bytes;
                mFreeChunks.insert_equal(*left);

                ret = right;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ret->mFree = false;
        }

        return reinterpret_cast<remote_ptr_t>(ret->mOffset);
    }

    remote_ptr_t malloc_aligned(remote_size_t bytes, remote_size_t alignment)
    {
        remote_size_t bufSize = bytes + alignment;
        remote_ptr_t mem = this->malloc(bufSize);
        remote_ptr_t ret = mem;
        if(mem)
        {
            remote_uintptr_t offset = reinterpret_cast<remote_uintptr_t>(mem);
            if(offset % alignment)
            {
                offset = offset + (alignment - (offset % alignment));
            }
            ret = reinterpret_cast<remote_ptr_t>(offset);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    void free(remote_ptr_t ptr)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        Chunk ref(reinterpret_cast<remote_uintptr_t>(ptr), 0, false);
        auto it = mAllChunks.find(ref);
        if(it == mAllChunks.end())
        {
            it = mAllChunks.upper_bound(ref);
            it--;
        }
        if(!(it->contains(ref.mOffset)) || it->mFree)
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not find chunk to free");

        Chunk *chnk = &(*it);
        chnk->mFree = true;
        mFreeChunks.insert_equal(*chnk);

        /* Maximize space */
        while(growFreeLeft(chnk));
        while(growFreeRight(chnk));
    }

    void debugDump()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        int i = 0;
        printf("----------- All chunks -----------\n");
        for(auto it = mAllChunks.begin(); it != mAllChunks.end(); it++)
        {
            printf(" [%d] %lu -> %lu (%lu) %s\n",
                i++,
                it->mOffset,
                it->mOffset + it->mSize,
                it->mSize,
                it->mFree ? "(FREE)" : "(NOT FREE)");
        }
        i = 0;
        printf("----------- Free chunks -----------\n");
        for(auto it = mFreeChunks.begin(); it != mFreeChunks.end(); it++)
        {
            printf(" [%d] %lu -> %lu (%lu) %s\n",
                i++,
                it->mOffset,
                it->mOffset + it->mSize,
                it->mSize,
                it->mFree ? "(FREE)" : "(NOT FREE)");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, off the top of my hat, of any canned implementation that can be used. However, this doesn't appear to be particularly difficult to implement yourself, using just the garden-variety containers in the C++ standard library.

I would recommend a simple approach that uses two `std::map`s and one `std::multimap`. Let's say that `bufaddr_t` is an opaque integer that represents an address in the external buffer. Since we're talking about 16 gig buffer, it has to be a 64 bit address:

```
typedef uint64_t memblockaddr_t;
```

Ditto for the size of an allocated block.

```
typedef uint64_t memblocksize_t;
```

You could, I suppose, use something else for `memblockaddr_t`, as long as the opaque data type has strict weak ordering.

The first part is easy. Keeping track of all allocated blocks:

```
std::map<memblockaddr_t, memblocksize_t> allocated;
```

So, when you successfully allocate a chunk of memory in the external buffer, you insert it here. When you wish to deallocate a chunk of memory, you look up the size of the allocated block here, and remove the map entry. Simple enough.

But that, of course, is not the whole story. Now, we need to keep track of available, unallocated memory blocks. Let's do it this way:

```
typedef std::multimap<memblocksize_t, memblockaddr_t> unallocated_t;

unallocated_t unallocated;

std::map<memblockaddr_t, unallocated_t::iterator> unallocated_lookup;
```

`unallocated` is a collection of all unallocated chunks in your external buffer, *keyed by chunk size*. The key is the chunk size. So, when you need to allocate a chunk of memory of a particular size, you can simply use the `lower_bound()` method (or `upper_bound()`, if you prefer) to immediately find the first chunk whose size is as least as much as you want to allocate.

And since you can, of course, have many chunks of the same size, `unallocated` has to be a `std::multimap`.

Also, `unallocated_lookup` is a map keyed by the address of each unallocated chunk, that gives you the iterator for this chunk's entry in `unallocated`. Why you need that will become clear in a moment.

So:

Initialize a new, completely unallocated buffer with a single entry:

```
memblockaddr_t beginning=0; // Or, whatever represents the start of the buffer.
auto p=unallocated.insert(std::make_pair(BUFFER_SIZE, beginning)).first;
unallocated_lookup.insert(std::make_pair(beginning, p));
```

Then:

1. To allocate a block, use the lower_bound()/upper_bound() approach as I mentioned above to find the first unallocated chunk that's at least as big and remove its entry from `unallocated` and `unallocated_lookup`. If it's more than what you need, return the excess back to the pool as if the extra amount that you don't need is being deallocated (step 3 below). Finally, insert it into the `allocated` array, so you remember how large the allocated chunk is.
2. To deallocate a block, look it up in the `allocated` array, to get its size, remove it from the `allocated` array, then:
3. Insert it into the `unallocated` and `unallocated_lookup`, similar to how the initial unallocated chunk was inserted, see above.
4. But you're not done yet. You must then use `unallocated_lookup` to trivially look up the preceding unallocated chunk and the following unallocated chunk in the memory buffer. If either or both of them are immediately adjacent to the newly-freed chunk, you must coalesce them together. That should be a very obvious process. You can simply go through the motions of officially removing the adjacent chunks individually, from `unallocated` and `unallocated_lookup`, then freeing a single, coalesced chunk.

That's the real purpose of `unallocated_lookup`, to be able to easily coalesce contiguous unallocated chunks.

As far as I can tell, all of the above operations carry logarithmic complexity. They're entirely based on `std::map`'s and `std::multimap`'s methods that have logarithmic complexity, and nothing else.

Finally:

Depending your application's behavior, you can easily tweak the implementation to internally round up the size of an allocated chunk to whatever multiple you wish. Or adjust the allocation strategy -- allocate from the smallest chunk that's big enough to meet the allocation request, or just allocate from the large unallocated chunk (simple, use `end()` to find it), etc...

That's one advantage to rolling your own implementation -- you'll always have much greater flexibility to tweak your own implementation, then you would typically have with some canned external library.